# Get 0 vaule return to controller from viewbag dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having the problem where I get 0 value return from my view bag Drop-down list. I don't have any problem for displaying list to my drop-down but when I submit the form, both of my drop down return 0 values to my controller. even, I selected the list.

Here is my code for Add controller.

```cs
public ActionResult Add()
{
    List<City> lstcCities = db.Cities.ToList();
    lstcCities.Insert(0, new City { Id = 0, Name = "Choose City" });

    List<County> lstCounties = db.Counties.ToList();
    lstCounties.Insert(0, new County { Id = 0, Name = "Choose County" });

    ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(lstcCities, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.CountyId = new SelectList(lstCounties, "Id", "Name");

    var category = db.Categories.ToList();
    var viewModel = new AdsViewModel
    {
        Category = category,
    };

    return View("Add", viewModel);
}
```

Here is my view code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Ads.City.Id)
    @Html.DropDownList("CityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ads.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Ads.County.Name)
    @Html.DropDownList("CountyId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ads.CountyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Here is my post action.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Ads ads, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images, 
    HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
{

    //Ensure model state is valid  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //check if images is null
        if (images != null)
        {
            var imageList = new List<AdsImage>();
            foreach (var image in images) //Loop for images for multiple uploading.
            {
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
                {
                    var data = br.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
                    var img = new AdsImage { AdsId = ads.Id };
                    img.ImageData = data;
                    imageList.Add(img);
                }
            }
            ads.AdsImage = imageList;
        }

        //Upload poster

        ////Add image to database
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ImageFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(ImageFile.FileName);
        fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        ads.Poster = "/Images/Ads_Image/" + fileName;
        fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images/Ads_Image/"), fileName);
        ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);


        ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Name", ads.CityId);
        ViewBag.CountyId = new SelectList(db.Counties, "Id", "Name", ads.CountyId);

        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ads.ApplicationUserId = userID;
        ads.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.Adses.Add(ads);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem or can help me with this problem
Thank you in advance for any helps.

Comment: it seems you are doing good but seems problem in model mapping...how are you posting data and mapping in post action ...share that code too..

Comment: Hi, that's what make me couldnt find solution for it. I have added my post action in my post if you please can have a look if there is something I've missed.

Comment: just checked..this is working ..seems name mismatch in ads model..

Comment: please provide the Ads model to check the if any naming mismatch exist